# Skype recorder with speach to text recognition?

Tags: skype, speech-recognition

I need a Skype conversations recorder with 2 features:

```
1. Group meetings recording.
2. Speech to text recognition.
```

Does anybody knows about such software?

Comment: I'm not sure if anybody knows about such software, but maybe speech-to-text would include correct spelling as well.

Answer (score 0):

[SuperTintin](http://www.supertintin.com/) will record Skype conversations (audio and video). You will be hard pressed to find anything to handle "Speech to text recognition" well.  I believe what you are actually talking about is voice transcription, which the state of the art is not that great yet. Google Voice is considered state of the art and if you have ever used it you will know that the transcription is not that accurate.  But often times it is good enough to get the jist of the conversation.  Most of the good transcription services use a combination of speech recognition and humans to get decent transcriptions. Probably one of the better consumer products available for transcription is [Dragon Naturally Speaking](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm).  They do have a [recorder application](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/recorder-app/index.htm) now.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I do not need translation, I need the speech to text recognition (at a minimum for English language only).

Comment: If you want a machine to take spoken input from a human and automatically provide a text representation of what was spoken then the term used for this technology in the Speech Community is transcription.  Transcription is the technology I referenced in my answer. If you are looking for something different please explain and I may be able to provide a better answer.

Comment: Yes, I need a different thing. Just Skype recorder that automatically converts recording to text.